# How to check if Application is running or not in background

Tags: android, android-service, android-background

I am developing an `Application` in which I want to start the `Application` on `Phone Start` and when `Application` is `Closed`. Basically when `Application` starts It will start a `service` or something which will check in `background` after 1 minute if `Application` is running or not.

If the `application` has been closed than it will start the `application`. I have implemented the first part by using the `BroadCast Receivers`. But I am unable to monitor the `application` status in background.

I used services and created a thread to check the `application` status (running or not) , but the service only works when application is running.

I need some suggestions.

Comment: start the service as a separate, unbounded process.

Comment: @Vinay, How can I do this ?

Answer (score 0):

There is no direct way to figure when your app gets in foreground or background. There is only the possibility of reference counting in your activities e.g. every onResume you add +1 and on every onPause you decrease by 1. If your count is 0, your whole app is in background, if not it's in foreground.